# fancy box player not working in chromium

Tags: jquery, video, flowplayer

i am developing web application and i download video playing plug-in. i made sum changes in downloaded code. it works good in Firefox but not working in chromium.but original plug-in  is working in Firefox and Chromium. only problem is my modified code was not working in chromium. i don't know where i am doing wrong. can any one help me to fix this?

this is the orginal plugin
 [link](http://www.picssel.com/demos/play_videos_with_mediaelement_in_fancybox.html)
i download all the necessary plug-ins

my modified code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="author" content="Jose Francisco Diaz / picssel.com" />
<title>Play mp4 videos with mediaelement.js in fancyBox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery2.1.5.fancybox.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery2.1.5.fancybox-buttons.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='me-player-css'  href='mediaelementplayer.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<style type="text/css">
/* this demo specific styles */
.fancybox-nav { width: 60px; }
.fancybox-nav span { visibility: visible; opacity: 0.5;}
.fancybox-nav:hover span {opacity: 1;}
.fancybox-next { right: -60px;}
.fancybox-prev { left: -60px;}
.fancybox-title-over-wrap {  top: 0;  left: 0;  bottom: auto;  position: absolute;  width: 100%;  z-index: 8035;}
#wrap ul {padding-left: 20px; font-size: 12px;}
#videolist {list-style-type: none; padding: 0;}
#videolist li {float: left;}
.fancy_video {position: relative; width: 162px; height:162px; display: block; float: left; margin: 10px 20px; z-index:1}
.fancy_video img {cursor:pointer; text-decoration: none; /* margin: 10px 20px;*/ padding: 5px; border: solid 1px #dedede; background-color: #f8f8f8; }
.fancy_video:hover img {background-color: #e8e8e8;}
.fancy_video:hover .playbutton {opacity: 0.7}
.playbutton {  background: transparent url("bigplay.png") no-repeat;  display: block;  height: 100px;  left: 31px;  opacity: 0.4;  overflow: hidden;  position: absolute;  top: 31px;  width: 100px;  z-index: 10;  cursor: pointer;}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery2.1.5.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="jquery2.1.5.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script src='mediaelement-and-player.min.js'></script>
<script>
/************************************************************************
Play mp4 videos with mediaelement.js in fancyBox
Francisco Diaz (JFK) / picssel.com
Version 1.0
************************************************************************/
// Detecting IE more effectively : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509.aspx
function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
    // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or -1 (other browser)
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    };
    return rv;
};
// set some general variables
var $video_player, _videoHref, _videoPoster, _videoWidth, _videoHeight, _dataCaption, _player, _isPlaying = false, _verIE = getInternetExplorerVersion();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  
    jQuery(".fancy_video")
    .prepend("<span class=\"playbutton\"/>") //cosmetic : append a play button image
    .fancybox({
        // set type of content (remember, we are building the HTML5 <video> tag as content)
        type       : "html",
        // other API options
        scrolling  : "no",
        padding    : 0,
        nextEffect : "fade",
        prevEffect : "fade",
        nextSpeed  : 0,
        prevSpeed  : 0,
        fitToView  : false,
        autoSize   : false,
        modal      : true, // hide default close and navigation buttons
        helpers    : {
            title  : {
                type : "over"
            },
            buttons: {} // use buttons helpers so navigation button won't overlap video controls
        },
        beforeLoad : function () {
            // if video is playing and we navigate to next/prev element of a fancyBox gallery
            // safely remove Flash objects in IE
            if (_isPlaying && (_verIE > -1)) {
                // video is playing AND we are using IE
                _verIE < 9.0 ? _player.remove() : $video_player.remove(); // remove player instance for IE
                _isPlaying = false; // reinitialize flag
            };
            // build the HTML5 video structure for fancyBox content with specific parameters
            _videoHref   = this.href;
            // validates if data values were passed otherwise set defaults
            _videoPoster = typeof this.element.data("poster")  !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("poster")  :  "";
            _videoWidth  = typeof this.element.data("width")   !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("width")   : 360;
            _videoHeight = typeof this.element.data("height")  !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("height")  : 360;
            _dataCaption = typeof this.element.data("caption") !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("caption") :  "";
            // construct fancyBox title (optional)
            this.title = _dataCaption ? _dataCaption : (this.title ? this.title : "");
            // set fancyBox content and pass parameters
            this.content = "<video id='video_player' src='" + _videoHref + "'  poster='" + _videoPoster + "' width='" + _videoWidth + "' height='" + _videoHeight + "'  controls='controls' preload='none' ></video>";
            // set fancyBox dimensions
            this.width = _videoWidth;
            this.height = _videoHeight;
        },
        afterShow : function () {
            // initialize MEJS player
            var $video_player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video_player', {
                    defaultVideoWidth : this.width,
                    defaultVideoHeight : this.height,
                    success : function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                        _player = mediaElement; // override the "mediaElement" instance to be used outside the success setting
                        _player.load(); // fixes webkit firing any method before player is ready
                        _player.play(); // autoplay video (optional)
                        _player.addEventListener('playing', function () {
                            _isPlaying = true;
                        }, false);
                    } // success
                });
        },
        beforeClose : function () {
            // if video is playing and we close fancyBox
            // safely remove Flash objects in IE
            if (_isPlaying && (_verIE > -1)) {
                // video is playing AND we are using IE
                _verIE < 9.0 ? _player.remove() : $video_player.remove(); // remove player instance for IE
                _isPlaying = false; // reinitialize flag
            };
        }
    });
}); // ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap" class="cf">

  <div class="cf">
    <ul id="videolist">

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://videos-f-5.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-prn/10374727_238077296386185_1685781536_n.mp4" data-width="620" data-height="570" data-poster="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-frc/t51.2885-15/10369513_880265978666597_548066800_n.jpg" data-caption="Michael Kors" title="Michael Kors"><img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-frc/t51.2885-15/10369513_880265978666597_548066800_s.jpg" alt="Michael Kors" /></a></li>

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://distilleryvesper3-19.ak.instagram.com/31fe43509e4011e3b9251256f5abc793_101.mp4" data-width="420" data-height="420" data-poster="http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-ash/915498_265573750285871_1139073698_n.jpg" data-caption="Lululemon" title="Lululemon"><img src="http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-ash/915498_265573750285871_1139073698_s.jpg" alt="Lululemon" /></a></li>

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://distilleryvesper11-7.ak.instagram.com/3758ff9ed9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4" data-width="480" data-height="480" data-poster="http://distilleryimage11.ak.instagram.com/3758ff9ed9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_7.jpg" data-caption="General Electric" title="General Electric"><img src="http://distilleryimage11.ak.instagram.com/3758ff9ed9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_5.jpg" alt="General Electric" /></a></li>

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://videos-d-13.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-prn/1968938_308401719313353_1339841628_n.mp4" data-width="380" data-height="380" data-poster="http://photos-d.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-prn/10009264_233225676872755_1395536783_n.jpg" data-caption="Mercedes Benz" title="Mercedes Benz"><img src="http://photos-d.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-prn/10009264_233225676872755_1395536783_s.jpg" alt="Mercedes Benz" /></a></li>

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0ce80e6b91111e3a16a122b8b9af17f_101.mp4"  data-poster="http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-ash/10011258_688891784492223_294700298_n.jpg" data-caption="Coca Cola" title="Coca Cola"><img src="http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-ash/10011258_688891784492223_294700298_s.jpg" alt="Coca Cola" /></a></li>

      <li><a class="fancy_video" data-fancybox-group="videoGallery" href="http://distilleryvesper3-7.ak.instagram.com/d7a2deba635811e3b6a7126315c1ffe7_101.mp4" data-width="480" data-height="480" data-poster="http://distilleryimage3.ak.instagram.com/d7a2deba635811e3b6a7126315c1ffe7_8.jpg" data-caption="Nike" title="Nike"><img src="http://distilleryimage3.ak.instagram.com/d7a2deba635811e3b6a7126315c1ffe7_5.jpg" alt="Nike" /></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div></div><!--wrap-->
</body>
</html
```